# Disable fb_sdk_settings_changed event from facebook-android-sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I recently enabled `AutoLogAppEventsEnabled=true`and then I noticed I received a violation warning in Facebook Events Manager. It seems my app sends a `fb_sdk_settings_changed` event with a parameter called `previous` that contains some sensitive health data.

Events Manager mentions that I should fix this.
In my code I never log such events and I assume the facebook sdk automatically logs them when it detects a preference change. Where/how can I intercept these events and prevent the facebook SDK from inserting specific user data parameters in those events?